# wpdb delete query count

Tags: database, count, wordpress

How do you count the number of times a delete query has been successfully executed using wordpress default database class.

for example:

```
$delete = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM table where and itemid > itemid");
```

I know one way is to fire a select count:

```
$deletecount = $wpdb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where itemid > itemid");
```

but is there a direct way to know the count without executing a second query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$wpdb->query(...)` function returns an integer value corresponding to the number of rows affected. So, if you delete `10` rows then it'll return `10`, use it like:

```
$count = $wpdb->query('delete query');
```

Also you may use the `delete` method:

```
$count = $wpdb->delete( $table, $where, $where_format = null );
```

Returns the same affected rows on successful operation and false on failure. Read more on [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#delete-rows).